# Pandas: time converter works in isolation but not when reading csv file

Tags: python, pandas, time, converters

I want to read a csv file and convert the Excel serial time value to a `YYYY-MM-DD` string. The file looks like this:

```py
A    B    start_date
0    yes  42736
1    no   42751
2    yes  43039
```

The function I want to use as a converter is:

```py
def convert_excel_time(excel_time):  
    return (pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01') + pd.to_timedelta(excel_time,unit='day')).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

And I am using it like this:

```py
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv",encoding = "ISO-8859-1",
                  converters={'start_date': convert_excel_time})
```

When using the function as a stand-alone, I get the correct result:

```py
excel_time = 42736
In[1]: (pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01')+pd.to_timedelta(excel_time,unit='day')).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
Out[1]: '2017-01-03'
```

However, if I use the function as a converter whilst reading the csv file, all my start dates are '1900-01-01'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It might be interpreting `start_date` as a string rather than an int, and that might be messing it up. Try putting `excel_time = int(excel_time)` at the start of your `convert_excel_time()` function, and see if that fixes it

Comment: That's exactly it! But how come it works ok in isolation? How come the casting of the `excel_time` variable is inconsistent? NB you can put it down as a proper answer for others to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, python tends to read files as strings. It generally does this unless you tell it to do otherwise. I'm not particularly familiar with how `pandas` does things, but that seems to be what's happening here: when `pd.read_csv()` reads your file, it interprets the `start_date` column as strings.

The [documentation for `pd.to_timedelta()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) says that it should read strings just fine. But when you actually test the method, it seems to not work in this particular case.

```
>>> pd.to_timedelta(44, "day")
Timedelta('44 days 00:00:00')
>>> pd.to_timedelta("44", "day")
Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00.000000')
```

I suspect that when it lists `str` as a valid argument, it's referring to a string representation of a TimeDelta, rather than an int-as-a-str. And for whatever reason, instead of raising an error, it just returns a zero-value when given that.

Consequently, you'll just need to make sure that you pass it an `int` instead of a `str`. The simplest way to do this is just to cast `excel_time` at the start of the function `convert_excel_time()`:

```
def convert_excel_time(excel_time):  
    excel_time = int(excel_time)
    return (pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01') + pd.to_timedelta(excel_time,unit='day')).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

When actually reading in the data, `pandas` seems to provide a mechanism to avoid this problem: the `dtype` kwarg for `pd.read_csv()` allows you to specify the expected type of each column (with `str` presumably being the default). The problem is that if you give a `converters` kwarg, it gets applied instead, so you have to handle the conversion yourself.